# drop check constraint when constraint name is not known

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Is it possible to delete check constraint(no constraint name declared) that is created within CREATE TABLE command?

Comment: Open the table in sql developer.  You might find that oracle named the constraint for you.

Comment: If you use SQL Developer, then indeed, connect with the right owner, open the table and navigate to the Constraints tab. You will find the same information that @VKP's solution will give you. You can also drop the constraint right from that tab. I don't use Toad, but I assume the same is possible in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the below query to find the list of check constraints in your table, including what they are checking for:

```
select constraint_name, search_condition
from user_constraints 
where table_name = 'Your table name'
and constraint_type = 'C' -- To filter Check constraints alone
```

Copy the name of the relevant constraint and paste it in the `Alter table drop constraint` command.

```
Alter Table Your_table_name 
       Drop Constraint constraint_name; -- Replace constraint_name from above query result
```

Comment: Is this the correct way ?

Alter Table Your_table_name Drop Constraint (select constraint_name, search_condition from user_constraints  where table_name = 'Your table name' and constraint_type = 'C');